# Determining an exponential(?) function from having just a few points

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I am trying to determine a function from knowing just a few of its outputs.

All I can do is describe it qualitatively and provide the datapoints.

The domain and range of the function are both 0-100

At x = 0, y also = 0, at x = 100, y also = 100, thus (0,0) and (100,100) exist.
As x increases from 0, the function starts off with y increasing very slowly, and at the half way point when x is 50, y is only ~15. Im not sure if this means it must be exponential or whether there are other types of non-linear functions that this could be, but it's obviously non-linear.
I also have one other point which is (83.6, 78)

I am not very versed at math, so had to use trial and error. I found that somewhere around 0.0004x^2.7 satisfies existence of both points at around 100,100 and 50,15, but around the x = 83.6 mark, y is only ~61.9, which means that the output hasnt "grown" fast enough up until there, and must be "growing" too steeply at the end.

But Im not sure how to fix it or where to go from here, or whether im even in the right ballpark for my type of function.

Comment: Note: I graphed my current approximation on a graphing calculator, and looking at the (83.6,78) point that the line would need to go through, it seems very steep at that x value. Intuitively it feels to me like it may actually be a piecewise function. Is there a way to verify whether this is piecewise or not?

Comment: I think it could be good you add the data points to the post.

Comment: All of the 4 data points I have were included in the original post.
For additional clarity, they are:
(0,0)
(50,15)
(83.6, 78)
(100,100)